# Dynamic phase Routing In Allegro

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, cadence, allegro

My doubt is regarding the dynamic phase control while routing differential pairs in allegro. If anyone knows kindly clear my doubts on these questions. For your reference, I have attached a snapshot here.
            1. Why dynamic phase is important in differential pairs?
            2. Kindly give clear content on How the dynamic phase works on 
              differential pairs?
            3. How to understand the DRC? And how to clear those DRC.
Thanks for your good answers

[![snapshot of dynamic phase routing(mismatches with constraints)
 ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpxga.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpxga.png)

Comment: Do you mean differential clock skew from unequal path lengths instead of dynamic phase control?

Comment: i dont know ,in allegro its named as dynamic phase .kindly clear my doubt if you have experience in this routing.thank you sir

Comment: Useful article. I suggest reading this first as it should clear up quite a bit. https://community.cadence.com/cadence_blogs_8/b/pcb/posts/a-shorter-predictable-design-cycle-for-complex-pcbs-dynamic-phase-control

Comment: i already read that but still it confusing

Comment: what is the clock rise time?  100 ps? 10ps? 1ns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best explained with a picture.

First, a little background.

A differential pair *should* have the same distance (within some reasonable margin) for each of the pairs, but that is not just the total track length; it also applies anywhere within the pair.

If the lengths diverge at any point, we will introduce [differential to common mode conversion](https://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/signal-integrity/4341070/Differential-to-common-mode-conversion).

So let's take a look at a pair with some of this:

[image: Memory strobe pair]

The little red arrow is pointing to one side of a DQS pair (as used in DDR4). The location pointed at is length matched to the DQ group and therefore is [serpentined](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-6103.pdf.pdf) (See page 5).

At the specific part of the serpentine pointed at, the upper trace is slightly longer than the lower trace, so the signals in each will take a slightly different amount of time to traverse the local area, leading to a phase mismatch between the pairs for a short distance.

This can be perfectly acceptable for very short runs which keeps the local mismatch to a minimum, but would not be acceptable for a long run which would produce a larger phase mismatch; the amount of phase mismatch determines the amount of energy lost (and radiated) from the differential pair.

So the importance of dynamic phase routing (as Cadence names it) is to *minimise signal loss and radiation* due to a local phase mismatch between the pair. This issue therefore has an impact on [EMC](http://www.newelectronics.co.uk/electronics-technology/emc-basics-and-practical-pcb-design-tips/169286/).

Static phase routing refers to the *overall length match* between the pairs.

**Edit**

The *maximum* dynamic phase length is the maximum deviation (in length) between the pairs at any point:

[image: DQASLengthDifference]

In the snapshot above, the difference in length at a section has been measured (0.574mm vs. 0.375mm) and they differ by 0.19mm which is a pretty tight match; the propagation of signals in most flavours of FR-4 is 160 psec/inch or 6.3 psec/mm. If I had a rule of no more than 2mm deviation (which would actually be reasonable for a high speed memory interface) then this difference would be well within it. If the distance across that area *exceeded* 2mm, a violation DRC would pop up.

I do not know what your DRC is; if you hover over it, there should be some explanatory text.

Comment: Thanks for your very good brief answer on dynamic phase routing,this is really helpful.i have one more confusion on that.what is max length in dynamic phase?,